# Error in SQL request on MySQL 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'd like to insert some values in my database using PHP. An error occures but I can't find why...

Here's my SQL query :

```
$req = "INSERT INTO 'event' 
('Date_Event', 'Place_Event', 'url_event') 
VALUES (DATE('{$date}','{$desc}','{$url}')";
```

Where `$date`, `$desc` and `$url` are respectively `2014-04-04 19:00:00`, `fefez` and `fdsfs` (I know that `$url` is not a proper url, that's just a test).

When I try to insert in directly in PHPMyAdmin, it works... Here's the `mysqli_error` I've got :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

```
'event' ('Date_Event', 'Place_Event', 'url_event') VALUES (DATE('2014-
```

> at line 1. Erreur lors de l'enregistrement

To create my query, I've used the SQL section in phpMyAdmin.
The "event" table is as follow :

- id_Event : int(4) and autoIncrement.
- Date_Event : datetime.
- Place_Event : varchar(100).
- url_event : varchar(200).

If anyone has an idea, help me, I beg you :'(

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you're having trouble with low-level SQL, you probably need a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to help structure your application and avoid having to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes represent literal strings. You need to use backticks around system tables and columns. I don't see why you need to cast the date since your column is `datetime` and you're using an ANSI date format.

```
INSERT INTO `event` (`Date_Event`, `Place_Event`, `url_event`)
VALUES ('{$date}', '{$desc}', '{$url}');
```

You should look into prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: or get rid of them altogether

Comment: just got late to reply so one up for you :-)

Comment: I don't see why you need the curly brackets

Comment: Well me neither but it works ! I didn't knew that backticks was mandatory for system tables and columns in MySQL... @FreshPrinceOfSO : I casted the date because I didn't knew what else to try. It works perfectly with your solution so I removed it

Comment: @Hahuha They're not mandatory, but recommended to avoid running into reserved words.

Comment: Well it seems that was the problem because it works just fine now. Thanks anyway !

Comment: The curly braces `{ }` aren't really needed. Presumably the entire query is wrapped in quotation marks ". You _need_ braces only if a variable name would "run into" other text (introduce ambiguity), but they don't hurt. Similarly, backticks are mandatory only for conflicts with reserved words, but it doesn't hurt to use them around table names and field names (just in case you don't realize you used a reserved keyword).